# Gradle not finding com.github.johnrengelman.shadow

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am running Micronaut project using JDK12 and Gradle 6.1.1, while compiling the project, its giving this error message.

**code**

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "groovy"
    id "application"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.2.0"
}
```

How to resolve this error?

```
build.gradle' line: 5

Plugin [id: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow', version: '5.2.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```